# Select all customers loyal to one company?

Tags: sql, select, join

I've got tables:

```
TABLE     | COLUMNS
----------+----------------------------------
CUSTOMER  |  C_ID, C_NAME, C_ADDRESS
SHOP      |  S_ID, S_NAME, S_ADDRESS, S_COMPANY
ORDER     |  S_ID, C_ID, O_DATE
```

I want to select id of all customers who made order only from shops of one company - 'Samsung' ('LG', 'HP', ... doesn't really matter, it's dynamic).

I've come only with one solution, but I consider it ugly:

```
( SELECT DISTINCT c_id FROM order JOIN shop USING(s_id) WHERE s_company = "Samsung" )
EXCEPT 
( SELECT DISTINCT c_id FROM order JOIN shop USING(s_id) WHERE s_company != "Samsung" );
```

Same SQL queries, but reversed operator. Isn't there any aggregate method which solves such query better?

I mean, there could be millions of orders(I don't really have orders, I've got something that occurs more often).

Is it efficient to select thousands of orders and then compare them to hundreds of thousands orders which have different company? I know, that it compares sorted things, so it's `O( m + n + sort(n) + sort(m) )`. But that's still large for millions of records, or isn't?

And one more question. How could I select all customer values (name, address). How can I join them, can I do just

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.* FROM CUSTOMER JOIN ( (SELECT...) EXCEPT (SELECT...) ) USING (C_ID);
```

*Disclaimer: This question ain't homework. It's preparation for the exam and desire to things more effective. My solution would be accepted at exam, but I like effective programming.*

Comment: GROUP BY combined with HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT S_ID) = 1

Comment: One customer can buy from more shops, but from shops with same company name 'S_COMPANY'. And even how do I add specific company to the query? `WHERE s_company="LG" GROUP BY c_id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s_company)=1` - this will be always true, because I select only rows from company I want. Without `WHERE` I can select customers loyal to one company, but not specific one.

Comment: Although not important for your question, it's good to also add the corresponding tag for the DBMS you are using (Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server...)

Comment: Standard SQL -> not specific DBMS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to approach this type of question using `group by` and a `having` clause.  You can get the list of customers using:

```
select o.c_id
from orders o join
     shops s
     on o.s_id = o.s_id
group by c_id
having min(s.s_company) = max(s.s_company);
```

If you care about the particular company, then:

```
having min(s.s_company) = max(s.s_company) and
       max(s.s_company) = 'Samsung'
```

If you want full customer information, you can join the customers table back in.

Whether this works better than the `except` version is something that would have to be tested on your system.

Comment: Wow. Smart one. If there are purchases only from one company, then it's first and last in alphabetical ordered list of companies for particular customer. And to select only from particular company, then I can compare first/last company in that list.

Comment: One more extra question. In the first example, if I wanted to select company name to which is customer loyal. How can I do it? I mean, I can't group only by 'c_id', because s.s_company could not be the same. By `having` clause it will be, but SQL server could not know that it will select only one company, ie. `min(a) = max(a)` -> `single(a)`.

Comment: @Miro . . . I don't understand the question in your comment.  What do you mean by "loyal"?  Perhaps this should be a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

How about a query that uses no aggregate functions like Min and Max?

```
select  C_ID, S_ID
from    shop
group by C_ID, S_ID;
```

Now we have a distinct list of customers and all the companies they shopped at. The loyal customers will be the ones who only appear once in the list.

```
select  C_ID
from    Q1
group by C_ID
having count(*) = 1;
```

Join back to the first query to get the company id:

```
with
Q1 as(
  select  C_ID, S_ID
  from    shop
  group by C_ID, S_ID
),
Q2 as(
  select  C_ID
  from    Q1
  group by C_ID
  having count(*) = 1
)
select  Q1.C_ID, Q1.S_ID
from    Q1
join    Q2
    on  Q2.C_ID = Q1.C_ID;
```

Now you have a list of loyal customers and the one company each is loyal to.

Comment: Nice solution. However, `min`/`max` solutions is quite shorter.